# Nio listing only a part of a directory

Tags: java, directory, nio

Because [File.list()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_list.htm) only list all files in a directory, I tried using nio library [Files.walkFileTree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.util.Set-int-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-), [Files.walk](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) and [Files.find](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#find-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.util.function.BiPredicate-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) which take more time but is more efficient (like listing files in subdirectory).

I can't find how to list only a part of the files on a directory. For example, I have more than 10k files and listing them all at one could cause memory issue so I'd like to work only with 500 files and do it again until everything is read.

What I am doing right now is :

```
List<String> result= new ArrayList<String>();
// try/catch
Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(path, maxDepth, (p, f) -> f.isRegularFile()) {
     result= stream.filter(Files::isRegularFile).map(s -> s.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Same thing with `File.walk()`

And

```
Files.walkFileTree(start, options, maxDepth, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path filePath, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        String fileName = filePath.getFileName().toString();
        result.add(fileName);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
});
```

I can't find options that would do that or a way not to read only a part of all the files in a directory. The first parameter for these functions is the folder to start reading not a file to begin with.

Comment: "_I can't find how to list only a part of the files on a directory._" Well, if those method return an ordered stream. You could use `skip` and `limit` to get only a subset. Of course, Having a list of `Path` doesn't load the file, so even of you would have 1M files, this would not overload the memory

Comment: So there is no issue at all because files aren't stored anywhere ? Even on appending files ?

Answer (score 0):

All optimization/laziness of Files.find is lost if you eagerly collect its result, i. e. call collect on the stream. The most memory efficient way is:

```
public static void list(Path path, int maxDepth, Consumer<Path> listFile) throws IOException {
    java.nio.file.Files.find(path, maxDepth, (p, f) -> f.isRegularFile()).forEach(listFile);
}

public static void exampleUse() throws IOException {
    list(Paths.get("."), 10, System.out::println);
}
```